# i can't install angular cli on my mac

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

1. I get below error while installing **angular-cli on** my **mac**
   current versions:

   - npm-5.6.0
   - node-v8.9.4

   ```
   npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macname/package.json'
   npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macname/package.json'
   npm WARN vinayak No description
   npm WARN vinayak No repository field.
   npm WARN vinayak No README data
   npm WARN vinayak No license field.
   ```
2. When I try to check current version of cli using `ng -v` I get the following error:
   `ng: command not found`
3. the follow details of my installing angular-cli,please ignore rxjs@^5.0.1 dependency

   ```
   npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
   npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.7: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
   npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue /Users/macname/.cli-global/bin/ng -> /Users/macname/.cli-global/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng
   npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
   ```

   using mac OS-10.13.3
4. I have password protection on my disc. Will it affect my installing? If yes give me solution for that, please.

Comment: use `npm install @angular/cli --gloabal` to install it globally, from point 1 it seems you are using `npm install angular-cli --save` command

Comment: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macname/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macname/package.json'
npm WARN macname No description
npm WARN macname No repository field.
npm WARN macname No README data
npm WARN macname No license field.

+ @angular/cli@1.7.1
removed 1 package and updated 1 package in 9.039s

Comment: after your command ,still not solved

Comment: what command did you use?

Comment: npm install @angular/cli --gloabal

Comment: if i use npm list -global --depth 0 i get answer like ├── @angular/cli@1.7.1
└── npm@5.6.0 ,but why my ng -v command return -bash: ng: command not found,really hectic now

Comment: to run `ng` command you have to create project and install `@angular/cli` as local dependency in that project. after installing that you can access `ng` command for that folder

Comment: how do i created u have any solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install `@angular/cli` globally using `--globally` and unable to access `ng` command please follow:

1. Create project directory using `mkdir test-project`
2. got to project directory using `cd test-project`
3. Now run `npm init` and follow the instruction
4. Now install @angular/cli locally using `npm install --save @angular/cli`
5. After installing locally you can access `ng` for that project

Note that to use `ng` you have to be in project directory.

EDIT: If this solution still not working for you, try running `npm link @angular/cli` if problem still exists Follow below steps.

- `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli`
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli`

in your `.bashrc` file append below command.

alias ng="~/.npm-global/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

restart terminal.

Notes :
Tested on
NODE version : 6.9.11
NPM version : > 5

Comment: still not working [macname-MacBook-Pro:test-project macname$ ng -v
-bash: ng: command not found

Comment: It seems Mac has path issue for ng alias, try `npm link @angular/cli` command and try if this is not working Follow below steps.

From neilhem commnets

npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli

in your .bashrc file append below command.

alias ng="~/.npm-global/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

restart terminal.

Notes :
Tested on
NODE version : 6.9.11
NPM version : > 5

Comment: where can i get .bashrc file

Comment: it is in your `home` dir, just open your terminal and run `nano ~/.bashrc` it wil l open .bashrc in editor for you

Comment: still no result,,do u have screenshot that might be help me lot

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, the same error, the same bash: ng: command not found and i'm running the newest version of High Sierra.
I'm no expert nor a newbie, but it seems for me that it is the new OS that is causing the problem.

Comment: your answer does not help at all to solve the problem

Comment: That is not directly true, all the comments above doesen't seem to help Shivvanand or me either, so maybe the problem is something to do with the new update from apple, at the moment I'm looking into updateting all of my software including the terminal software on my computer, if any succes then i will state it here (he and I, for that matter, has been struckling with this situation for some time now, so I guess it's nice to know that problem is not totally forgotten, I hope that makes sense )